# Using a static class fuction causes a linker error thanks to an "unresolved external symbol" but I have no idea how to fix it?

Tags: c++, cmake

I've been recently following the Game Engine series from the cerno, but I have a lot of trouble following a certain part of the series. I've also did the project using CMake instead of Visual Studio in order to learn a new skill. My problem is the following. I am writing a interface class called Log:

**Log.h**

```
#pragma once
#include <memory>

#include "spdlog/spdlog.h"
#include "spdlog/sinks/stdout_color_sinks.h"

namespace csl{

    class Log {
    private:
        static std::shared_ptr<spdlog::logger> s_CoreLogger;
        static std::shared_ptr<spdlog::logger> s_ClientLogger;

    public:
        static void Init();

        inline static std::shared_ptr<spdlog::logger>& GetCoreLogger() { return s_CoreLogger; }
        inline static std::shared_ptr<spdlog::logger>& GetClientLogger() { return s_ClientLogger; }
    };
}
```

**Log.cpp**

```
#include "Log.h"

namespace csl {
    std::shared_ptr<spdlog::logger> Log::s_CoreLogger;
    std::shared_ptr<spdlog::logger> Log::s_ClientLogger;

    void Log::Init()
    {
        spdlog::set_pattern("%^[%T} %n: %v%$");

        s_CoreLogger = spdlog::stdout_color_mt("Constellate");
        s_CoreLogger->set_level(spdlog::level::trace);

        s_ClientLogger = spdlog::stdout_color_mt("APP");
        s_ClientLogger->set_level(spdlog::level::trace);

    }
}
```

I am then trying to use this logging class: **EntryPoint.h**

```
#ifdef CSL_PLATFORM_WINDOWS

    extern csl::Application* csl::CreateApplication();

    #include <iostream>

    int main() {
        csl::Log::Init();
        csl::Log::GetCoreLogger()->warn("Mom, I'm ultra scared.");

        std::cout << "Created entry point.";
        auto* app = csl::CreateApplication();
        app->Run();
        delete app;
    }

#endif
```

The problem is that when I include the line `csl::Log::GetCoreLogger()->warn("Mom, I'm ultra scared.");`, I get this linker error: *Error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol*

I determined that happens because `s_CoreLogger` is not properly defined inside EntryPoint.cpp. I can redefine it locally to avoid the error as such:

```
std::shared_ptr<spdlog::logger> csl::Log::s_CoreLogger;

#ifdef CSL_PLATFORM_WINDOWS

    extern csl::Application* csl::CreateApplication();

    #include <iostream>

    int main() {
        csl::Log::Init();
        csl::Log::GetCoreLogger()->warn("Mom, I'm ultra scared.");

        std::cout << "Created entry point.";
        auto* app = csl::CreateApplication();
        app->Run();
        delete app;
    }

#endif
```

This will stop the linker error but `s_CoreLogger` will appear as null. It's pretty clear to me that I am somewhat trapped in a static initialization problem or something like that but I can't figure out why it works for TheCerno while it does not work for me. I will also include the **CMakeLists.txt**

```
project (ConstellateEngine VERSION 1.0)

add_library("${PROJECT_NAME}" SHARED  "src/Core/Log.cpp" "src/Core/Application.cpp"  "src/Core/Core.h")

target_include_directories("${PROJECT_NAME}" PUBLIC "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src")
```

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.23.1)

project (ConstellateProject VERSION 1.0)

set(CMAKE_WINDOWS_EXPORT_ALL_SYMBOLS ON)     #Required for exporting the symbols in DLLs
#set( CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE on )   #Makes it so you can see the final linker command created by CMake
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

set (CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bin")   #Put the libraryes and executable in the same place
set (CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bin")


add_compile_definitions(CSL_PLATFORM_WINDOWS)

add_subdirectory(spdlog)
add_subdirectory(ConstellateEngine) 

#spdlog library
target_link_libraries("ConstellateEngine" PRIVATE spdlog::spdlog)
target_include_directories("ConstellateEngine" PUBLIC "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/spdlog/include")

#_________________________

add_subdirectory(Game)
target_link_libraries("Game" PRIVATE "ConstellateEngine")
```

**Game.cpp** includes **Constellate.h** witch in turns includes **EntryPoint.h**

```
#include <iostream>

#include <Constellate.h>
#include <iostream>

class Game : public csl::Application {

public:
    Game() {

    }
    ~Game(){

    }
};

//This is the entry point of the library
csl::Application* csl::CreateApplication()
{
    return new Game();
}
```

**Constellate.h**

```
#include "Core/Application.h"  //The container that manages the entry point of the application.
#include "Core/Log.h"  //The container that manages the entry point of the application.

//Application entry
#include "Core/EntryPoint.h"
```

Comment: `EntryPoint.h` is not used anywhere in the code you are showing. And you are not showing any `EntryPoint.cpp` at all. My guess is that you have some issue with how that is setup. That you are building a shared library instead of an executable is suspicious. You must have another cmake file building an executable, right? Also header files do not belong in `add_library`. The files you are showing are also missing stuff like includes at the beginning. Please reduce your code to a [mre] and show it in full.

Comment: `csl::Log::Init()` should solve the problem of the startic smart pointer being null. It would probably be preferrable to use magic static here (`[[nodiscard]] std::shared_ptr<spdlog::logger> GetCoreLogger() { static std::shared_ptr<spdlog::logger> logger = CreateInitializedLogger(); return logger; }` (note: you may need to move the implementation to a cpp file)) . Definetly returning a reference to non-const is an possible issue, since the user of the caller of the function could call `reset()` on the pointer returned. Either return a copy of the shared pointer or simply return a reference.

Comment: `s_CoreLogger` is properly defined in `Log.cpp`. If it is listed as an undefined symbol, then you are not linking that file properly. You should fix that, rather than insert another definition elsewhere. Also please [do not post images of errors or code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question).

Comment: The `EntryPoint.*` files still are not used anywhere in the other source files or cmake files.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. the issue went away after getting rid of inline in the declaration of the  GetCoreLogger() fuction. Everythink to do with linking, the CMake files, are already included.

Comment: @fabian I am not exatly sure what you said. Moving the implementation of `GetCoreLogger` and `GetClientLogger` inside the .cpp file seems to have solved the problem. Something to do with those 2 fuctions being inline caused the issue. I wish I understoob better what happened.

Comment: I see the problem now. You are on Windows using DLLs. Windows DLLs have somewhat weird semantics. It is not a good idea to export an inline function from a DLL if it touches any static data.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so for anyone having a problem that kind of looks like this, the real problem with this piece of code is how those 2 fuctions were written:

```
inline static std::shared_ptr<spdlog::logger>& GetCoreLogger() { return s_CoreLogger; }
inline static std::shared_ptr<spdlog::logger>& GetClientLogger() { return s_ClientLogger; }
```

It seems something to do with exporting global variables as a DLL using CMake or fuctions being overwritten every time Log.h is included. Either way, just moving the implementation in the .cpp and avoid inline seems to fix the problem.

**Log.cpp**

```
#include "Log.h"

namespace csl {
    std::shared_ptr<spdlog::logger> Log::s_CoreLogger;
    std::shared_ptr<spdlog::logger> Log::s_ClientLogger;

    void Log::Init()
    {
        spdlog::set_pattern("%^[%T} %n: %v%$");

        s_CoreLogger = spdlog::stdout_color_mt("Constellate");
        s_CoreLogger->set_level(spdlog::level::trace);

        s_ClientLogger = spdlog::stdout_color_mt("APP");
        s_ClientLogger->set_level(spdlog::level::trace);

    }

     std::shared_ptr<spdlog::logger>& Log::GetCoreLogger() {
        return s_CoreLogger;
    }
     std::shared_ptr<spdlog::logger>& Log::GetClientLogger() {
        return s_ClientLogger;
    }
}
```

**Log.h**

```
//#include <memory>
#include <memory>

#include "spdlog/spdlog.h"
#include "spdlog/sinks/stdout_color_sinks.h"

//Class that takes care of logging across all the engine systems


namespace csl{

    class Log {
    private:
        static std::shared_ptr<spdlog::logger> s_CoreLogger;
        static std::shared_ptr<spdlog::logger> s_ClientLogger;

    public:
        static void Init();

         static std::shared_ptr<spdlog::logger>& GetCoreLogger();
         static std::shared_ptr<spdlog::logger>& GetClientLogger();
    };
}
```